# Integrals of operator valued and Hilbert space valued functions

Tags: integration, measure-theory, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Consider a Hilbert space $H$ and the set of bounded operators $B(H)$. I am interested in integrating functions of the form $f:X \to H$ and $A: X \to B(H)$ where $X$ is generally a measure space, but for simplicity let's consider $X= \mathbb{R}$ (and I suppose these will have to be continuous, or have at most discontinuities of measure 0). Can/How is such an integral defined generally and under what assumptions on $X$,$f$,$A$?  If it can be defined, are the integrals of $f(x)$ and of $A(x)$ "compatible", in the sense that the integral of the operators $A(x)$ acting on any $Ψ\in H$ equals the integral of $A(x)Ψ$:
$$\int_0^T A(x) \,dx   \, Ψ = \int_0^T A(x)Ψ \, dx$$
Are the "exprected" properties satisfied, like $$|| \int_0^T A(x) \,dx|| \leq \int_0^T ||A(x)|| \, dx $$
or $$ \langle Ψ, \int_0^T f(x) \,dx \rangle = \int_0^T \langle Ψ, f(x)\rangle \,dx \ \forall Ψ \in H $$
Is such an integral uniquely defined?

I would really appreciate Refences on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

That's the Bochner integral : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral